# how to use connection pooling for client in javax.ws.rs.client

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to communicate with a server using `https` service

I am able to communicate but it takes 2 Secs response time..

Now, I want to reduce time for SSL handshake for every request

So, I want to cache or keep the connection live or create pooling connection..

Any suggestions..

My Code:

```
  static SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator
                .newInstance()
                .securityProtocol("TLS")
                .keyStoreFile("/path")
                .keyStorePassword("password")
                .keyStoreType("JKS")
                .trustStoreFile(
                        "/path");

    static SSLContext sslCtx = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
    static Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslCtx).build();
    Response response = client.target(target).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(Entity.entity(jsonRequest.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: Create a pool of `Client`s (for instance using `commons-pool2`) I assume that the `Client` is thread safe and ready for reuse.

Comment: can you provide some sample to create pools or reference

Comment: [Here](http://www.theotherian.com/2013/08/jersey-client-2.0-httpclient-timeouts-max-connections.html) is an even better solution, using the apache http library. If you don't want to use the http client then read the commons-pool [doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html).