# how to do connection pooling on a https server (to reduce time on ssl handshake)in java (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, connection-pooling

I am trying to communicate on https with a server and get a response , but for each request it does a handshake and gives response so for this process it is taking around 2 sec so i want to do a connection pooling with the server to reduce handshake time for every request , so how to do connection pooling in java (is helpful even using spring frame)

I am seeing results for only db connection pooling on net but i want to make it on a https server

Comment: Create a datasource instead in server.

Comment: you can also use DBCP by apache, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: i want to make connection to a application server not database server

Comment: How are you connection? What are you using? Depending on the solution you could use apache http client and configure it with a pool of connections.

Comment: see my implementation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607653/how-to-use-connection-pooling-for-client-in-javax-ws-rs-client

Comment: Plesae don't open a new question, edit your question instead. I marked this one as a duplicate...